# Explanation about phonegap environment

Tags: cordova

I am using Phonegap to develop a android/ios apps.
But there are some question about the environment definition.

During build the environment,I have install the following applications:

NodeJS,
Ant,
Phonegap ,
JAVA JDK,
Android sdk

During build a apps, Can someone tell me what their respective functions are?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Android SDK is the primary tool to build native apps for the Android platform. Android uses Java, so the Java SDK is required as well.

PhoneGap is the actual CLI used to build PhoneGap apps, and it wraps/uses the Android SDK behind the scenes.

NodeJS is used just to get npm which you used to install PhoneGap. I don't think you use it again after that, but a lot of tools nowadays use npm for installation, so keep it around.

Comment: Ant is used - I believe - by some of the Android tools. Once you install it and add it to your PATH, you can forget about it.